# View a Minecraft skin as a 3D model?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm trying to create a skin for Minecraft for the first time. I loaded it as my character's skin so that I could see it, but since the head moves around with my mouse I can't see the top, bottom, and sides of the head.

Is there a way to see the skin as a 3D model and be able to pan around it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out [SkinEdit](http://orcsinthebasement.com/skinedit), which will let you edit and view your skin in 3D without constraints. It works for all platforms that support Java: OS X, Windows, Linux, etc.

[image: Screenshot of SKinEdit]

When you download it, you'll get a JAR file, SkinEdit.jar: you should be able to just double-click on it to launch it. Once loaded, just click and drag on the model in the bottom-right corner to pan around and see your skin in action.

Comment: The bottom right box says "Preview broken". I'm using Windows btw, and when I run Launch.bat it says it failed to find my Java installation which doesn't make sense

Comment: nevermind I fixed it by deleting the skintest2.jar file and then restarting the program and clicking OK

Answer (score -1):

I recommend [MCSkin3D](http://www.planetminecraft.com/mod/mcskin3d/). It is popular, professional-looking, and has skin management, and editing features.
[image: Picture of MCSkin 3D]