# Minecraft skin script

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [View a Minecraft skin as a 3D model?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/79112/view-a-minecraft-skin-as-a-3d-model)

Is there a way from the base of a minecraft skin it will show a 2d picture of it from all sides like planet minecraft does?

If no one knows or can find a script like that then can there show me how to get each pixel of a image and place it somewhere else on a picture and put it together. With javascript or any other type of code which can be viewed in the web browser.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is going to be an online editor like [Novaskin](http://www.olgh.net/minecraft-1-1-novaskin-online-skin-editor/). This will allow you to edit your skin and see the results on a model in real time.